# How do I change the color of span inside a button inside another span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like this:

```
<span class="no1">
<button class="num1"><span class="abc"></span></button>
<button class="num2"><span class="abc"></span></button>
</span>
<span class="no2">
<button class="num1"><span class="abc"></span></button>
<button class="num2"><span class="abc"></span></button>
</span>
```

Now, I want to change the color of span with class `abc`, inside class `num1` button, inside class span `no2`

I tried `$(".no2").children('.num1').css('color', 'orange')`

Comment: You almost have it, you need to get the span of the button, so change to this `$(".no2").find('.num1').find('.abc').css('color', 'orange');` This says, find element with class `no2`, then find a decendant with class `num1` then find a decendant of that with class `abc`, and set it's `css`.

Comment: `$('.no2 .num1 .abc')` or `$('.no2 .abc')`

Comment: @JohnDoe Or as Mohamed-Yousef pointed out, you can chain the classes together in your selector to make it even less code.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I think your second selector would produce undesired results, wouldn't it style both spans under `no2` to have the color then?

Comment: @RyanWilson yes .. you're right I didn't notice the `num2` class :-)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef No worries, just thought I'd try to help, you presented a good option as it can then all fit inside the selector. :)

Comment: @icecub No worries. :)

Answer (score 3):

According to your Question you want to change the color of the `span class="abc"` element which is inside `span` having `class="num1"` and `span class="no2"`

```
$(".no2 .num1 .abc").css("color","orange);
```

In jQuery $(selector nextSelector) reprents the $("ancestor descendant" )

A descendant of an element could be a child, grandchild, great-grandchild, and so on, of that element.

Comment: This encompasses what has been said in the comments with a good explanation of how chaining in a selector works. +1

Answer (score 1):

Just to piggy-back on Sushil's answer [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelector) mimics this behaviour if you ever decided to ditch jQuery.

```js
const b = document.querySelector('.no2 .num1 .abc');
b.classList.add('blue');
```

```css
.blue { color: blue };
```

```html
<span class="no1">
<button class="num1"><span class="abc">test1</span></button>
<button class="num2"><span class="abc">test2</span></button>
</span>
<span class="no2">
<button class="num1"><span class="abc">test3</span></button>
<button class="num2"><span class="abc">test4</span></button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select the element using jQuery as so:

```
 $(.no1 .num1).first().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Please find this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jega1syb/#&togetherjs=bVGaanQ61z